# PyOpengl: Changing gluPerspective variables makes cube flash

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

When using gluPerspective in glutReshapeFunc function, the square image flashes while resizing and is gone after a few moments.

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

width = 500
height = 500


def cube():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0)
    glVertex3f(10, 0, 0)
    glVertex3f(10, 10, 0)
    glVertex3f(10, 0, 0)
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0)
    glVertex3f(10, 0, 0)
    glVertex3f(10, 0, 10)
    glVertex3f(0, 10, 0)
    glVertex3f(10, 10, 0)
    glVertex3f(0, 10, 0)
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0)
    glVertex3f(0, 10, 0)
    glVertex3f(0, 10, 10)
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 10)
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0)
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 10)
    glVertex3f(10, 0, 10)
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 10)
    glVertex3f(0, 10, 10)
    glVertex3f(10, 10, 10)
    glVertex3f(10, 10, 0)
    glVertex3f(10, 10, 10)
    glVertex3f(10, 0, 10)
    glVertex3f(10, 10, 10)
    glVertex3f(0, 10, 10)
    glEnd()


def showScreen():
    global width, height

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    cube()
    glutSwapBuffers()


def mouseTracker(mousex, mousey):
    print(f"Mouse pos: {mousex}, {mousey}")


def reshapeWindow(x, y):
    global width, height
    width = x
    height = y
    print(x, y)
    gluPerspective(45, (width / height), 0.0001, 1000)



glutInit()
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA)
glutInitWindowSize(500, 500)
wind = glutCreateWindow("OpenGL")
glutDisplayFunc(showScreen)
glutIdleFunc(showScreen)
glutMotionFunc(mouseTracker)
glutPassiveMotionFunc(mouseTracker)
glutReshapeFunc(reshapeWindow)
gluPerspective(45, (width / height), 0.0001, 1000)
glTranslatef(0, 0, -5)

while True:
    glutMainLoopEvent()
    glutPostRedisplay()
```

If I put the gluPerspective into the showScreen function like so:

```
def showScreen():
    global width, height

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    cube()
    gluPerspective(45, (width / height), 0.0001, 1000)
    glutSwapBuffers()
```

The square flashes without resizing but it is gone after a few moments. If I remove the gluPerspective entirely, the image turns into a triangle. Is there any way to change gluPerspective variables without making the image flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `gluPerspective` before drawing the cube. The matrix operations not only set the current matrix, but define a new matrix and multiply the current matrix by the new matrix. Therefore you must load the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) with [`glLoadIdentity`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml) before modifying the matrix. The legacy OpenGL provides different current matrices for the model view matrix and the projection matrix. Before changing a matrix, select the matrix mode with [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml):

Change the projection matrix in the `reshape` callback:

```py
def reshapeWindow(x, y):
    global width, height
    width = x
    height = y
    print(x, y)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(45, (width / height), 0.0001, 1000)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
```

Set the model view matrix before the application loop or in the application loop:

```py
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()
glTranslatef(0, 0, -5)
```

[`gluPerspective`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) defines a [Viewing frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum). The center of the view is (0, 0). Hence you need to change the vertex coordinates.

I suggest enabling the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) when drawing 3D meshes.

Minimale example based on your code:

```py
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
import time

width = 500
height = 500

vertices = [(-1,-1,-1), ( 1,-1,-1), ( 1, 1,-1), (-1, 1,-1), (-1,-1, 1), ( 1,-1, 1), ( 1, 1, 1), (-1, 1, 1)]
faces = [(4,0,3,7), (1,0,4,5), (0,1,2,3), (1,5,6,2), (3,2,6,7), (5,4,7,6)]
colors = [(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1)]

def cube():
    glRotatef(1, 3, 1, 1)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    for i, face in enumerate(faces):
        glColor3fv(colors[i])
        for vertex in face:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
    glEnd()

def showScreen():
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    cube()
    glutSwapBuffers()

def mouseTracker(mousex, mousey):
    print(f"Mouse pos: {mousex}, {mousey}")

def reshapeWindow(x, y):
    global width, height
    width = x
    height = y
    print(x, y)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(45, (width / height), 0.0001, 1000)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

glutInit()
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA)
glutInitWindowSize(500, 500)
wind = glutCreateWindow("OpenGL")
glutDisplayFunc(showScreen)
glutIdleFunc(showScreen)
glutMotionFunc(mouseTracker)
glutPassiveMotionFunc(mouseTracker)
glutReshapeFunc(reshapeWindow)

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()
glTranslatef(0, 0, -5)

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

while True:
    glutMainLoopEvent()
    glutPostRedisplay()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```